# Handling Large Images in android without compromising in image quality

Tags: android, memory

I am trying to build an application to vary the contrast,brightness etc of the Image and display it.I am not able to handle large images.Is there any way I can handle Large images without losing Image quality?
PS:I have done quite a lot of search on the topic and was not able to find any solution.
Thank you in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be hard to answer your question without examples. However, I would advise you to review this article that specifically deals with how to handle [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

The article covers how to:

1. Read Bitmap Dimensions and Type
2. Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory

And yes, I know that you are not wanting to loose image quality, but this article gives you the best guidelines to follow and should get you close to what you want. There are cases where you will need to scale the image down and cases where you do not need to do so.